# Parse to heroku cloud-code not working

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-cloud-code

I am able to run a sample piece of cloud code on Parse-Server, but when I use get commands to retrieve data from a class in the DB in the cloud code, I get an error.

These worked on Parse.com, but now that I am running them on Parse-Server via Heroku, they fail. I am wondering if I should be formatting the "look-ups" differently.

I can't find any references to this in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the get() query to work by:

in index.js i had serverURL set to 'http://localhost:1337'
i had also tried 'http://localhost:1337/parse'

I then tried the actual link to my project, with /parse included
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/"given-name"/resources/parse